# toString() unavailable - no suspended threads and loop stops running - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

A loop in a code I'm writing in Java at Android Studio stops running sometimes at a different number of iterations and the application just stop working.

I tried to debug it on eclipse. It starts fine but in some point it gets stuck and gives me the error: [toString() unavailable - no suspended threads]

when i researched the error i found it was a bug on eclipse but it is getting stuck also in Android Studio (I added a Log message to show me in which iteration it stopped and it is different every time).

anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

I added the code below

```
public int[] createBoard(){
    int lastMove = -2;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        lastMove = swapBoard(emptyCube, lastMove);
    }

    return boardCubes;
}

private int swapBoard(int emptyCube , int lastMove){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] validMoves = {UP_OR_DOWN, -UP_OR_DOWN, LEFT_OR_RIGHT, -LEFT_OR_RIGHT};

    int nextMove = 30;
    while(emptyCube + nextMove >= NUM_OF_CUBES || emptyCube + nextMove <0 || nextMove == -lastMove)
        nextMove = validMoves[rand.nextInt(3)];

    swap(emptyCube + nextMove);

    return nextMove;
}
```

Comment: are you using any kind of thread?? toString() is not thread safe I think

Comment: I guess it should be due to StackOverFlow error since it a recursion .

Comment: it's not a recursion, its a regular loop runs from 0 to 100
also I'm not using any thread